# Не удаётся подключиться к MongoDB (Java)

Tags: java, android, mongodb

Пытаюсь подключить к своему Android-приложению удалённую базу MongoDB:

```
try {
            String str = "";
            MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://byulent:mypass@ds231549.mlab.com:31549/mydb");
            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
            MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase(uri.getDatabase());
            MongoCollection<Document> photos = db.getCollection("photos");
            FindIterable<Document> cursor = photos.find();
            Iterator i = cursor.iterator();
            while (i.hasNext()){
                Log.d("obj", i.next().toString());
            }
            //Toast.makeText(context, "Succesfully connected to MongoDB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("mongodb", e.getMessage());
        }
```

Но при попытке получения данных из коллекции мне постоянно выводится следующая ошибка:

```
E/mongodb: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state 
is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=ds231549.mlab.com:31549, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING,
exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by 
{java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to ds231549.mlab.com/34.245.70.193 
(port 31549) after 20000ms}}]
```

Появляется ошибка на этапе действия итератора.

Поначалу грешил на необходимость подключения VPN для доступа к Mlab, но, когда подключился, ошибка не исчезла.

Из-за чего это происходит и как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Возможная причина - несоответствие драйвера и версии mongo сервера, сравните какой JAR и какой фактически версии сервер? (Отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/a/38570463/5892568)

Comment: По таблице совместимости всё нормально - драйвер 3.7 совместим с Mongo 3.4

Comment: Вообще чтение монги из Android приложения это анти-паттерн, надо тащить драйвер, разбираться с проблемами сети и т.д. Я бы рекомендовал сделать веб-сервис который будет забирать данне из mongo и отдавать. Благо на node это делается очень просто используя разные фреймворки, как в прочем и на Java, PHP и т.д.

Comment: антипаттерн антипаттерном, а времени нет